What performance norms do I need for the USCF candidate master title?
The rating requirement is 2000-2199 but what performance norms do I need?

According to this pdf file, you need five performance norms at the 2000 level to earn the candidate master title. That document also explains how to calculate whether a performance in an event qualifies for a norm.
